# "Same as above" representation

Tags: macros, longtable

When I have a table, where one row has the same content as above, is there a representation for that in latex?

In Germany we sometimes use `------- " --------` to say that the line here is the same as above.

So instead of having this:

```
| title | description          |
| Bla   | no description       |
| Blubb | no description       |
| Blop  | no description       |
| Blip  | no description       |
```

Have something like this:

```
| title | description          |
| Bla   | no description       |
| Blubb | ---------"---------- |
| Blop  | ---------"---------- |
| Blip  | ---------"---------- |
```

Maybe not with the dashed line, but a straight line. Is there a command for that or any other way to say that one line is above the other, without writing "see above"?

Forgot to mention:
I use the `longtable` environment. My column types are `{c|lp{4cm}p{4cm}}`

Comment: Related question: [Is there a ditto symbol?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53823/3323)

Comment: What is the column type of `description`?

Comment: @diabonas Yes, that is the symbol I'm looking for. However, I would want to center the symbol, in a (To Werner) p{5cm} column type.

Comment: Don't use "ditto marks"; if the value can be inferred from the line above omit it, otherwise write it. You'll do a favor to your readers. :)

Comment: @egreg How come? Are there certain guidelines?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a draft of what you might be after, using the [`xhfill` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/xhfill) (for leaders) and `\textquotedbl` (via the `T1` encoding from [`fontenc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontenc), as suggested in [Is there a ditto symbol?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53823/5764)):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fontenc
\usepackage{longtable}% http://ctan.org/pkg/longtable
\usepackage{xhfill}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xhfill
\newcommand{\ditto}[1][.4pt]{\xrfill{#1}~\textquotedbl~\xrfill{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{c|lp{4cm}p{4cm}}
\hline
Title & Heading & Description & Blop \\
Bla   & A & no description & Blop \\
Blubb & B & \ditto & Blip  \\
Blop  & C & \ditto & Blubb \\
Blip  & D & \ditto[1pt] & Blop  \\
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}​
```

`xhfill` is not *really* required, but it's small enough to use as-is. The default width of the leader/rule drawn by `\xrfill` is `.4pt` according to the definition of `\ditto[<width>]`, unless specified otherwise.

Comment: Very nice. My `textquotedbl` results in curved quotes, instead of straigt ones. Is there a way to force straight ones? And I noticed that the lines are pretty close to the top row, especially if the text in a preceding column spans multiple rows. Is it possible to have a top margin?

Comment: If, by "pretty close to the top row" you mean that the leader (horizontal line) is "too high", you can use `\xrfill[.7ex]{#1}` in your definition of `\ditto` instead. `\xrfill` takes an optional argument that raises the horizontal leader (default is `1ex`).

Comment: It may also be feasible to use `\renewcommand{\textquotedbl}{\texttt{"}}` if you don't want to use a different font encoding that supplies `\textquotedbl` (like `T1` does).

Comment: Thanks for the advice with `\renewcommand`. By "too close" I actually mean that if I have an `\hline` both the hline and the `\ditto` are very close to each other. See: http://d.pr/i/OHbM Would be nice to have a "top margin".

Comment: Perhaps try this definition of `\ditto`: `\newcommand{\ditto}[1][1ex]{\xrfill[.7ex]{.4pt}~\rule{0pt}{#1}\textquotedbl~\xrfill[.7ex]{.4pt}}` and then you can use `\ditto[\normalbaselineskip]` for the first row with an `\hline` above it, and just `\ditto` everywhere else. The optional argument to `\ditto` now takes a length that denotes the vertical strut inserted rather than the width of the leader. The width is now fixed to `.4pt` (the usual LaTeX default rule width).

Comment: Yes, I like that, but was wondering, if it is also possible to just align it vertically? So that it's horizontally AND vertically aligned?

Comment: @cherrung: You can move `\textquotedbl` up/down using `\strut\smash{\raisebox{<len>}{\textquotedbl}}` where you specify any `<len>`. The `\strut` is in lieu of the zero-height `\smash`, although it may not be entirely necessary since there's content on the same row in other cells.