# Tikz: use latex length for length of path (ditto marks)

Tags: tikz-pgf, typography, width, lengths

I want to draw a ditto line, which is a horizontal line with two small marks in the middle.

My first attempt was `\dittoLatex` which uses a box with characters and rules, but is frankly ugly.

My second attempt was `\dittotikzA` which looks a lot better, but does not calculate its width automatically from an argument.

My third attempt is `\dittotikzB` which attempts to use the same method for calculating the width as `\dittoLatex`, but it doesn't work. I suspect the issue is with mismatching units, but I can't figure out how to fix it.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{xparse}

\makeatletter

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\newcommand\dittotikzA[1][3em]{%
    \def\x{#1/4}%
    %\show\x%
    \def\y{#1*.01}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1ex,y=1ex,baseline=-.5ex,cap=round]
        \draw (0,0) sin (1*\x,\y) cos (2*\x,0) sin (3*\x,-\y) cos (4*\x,0);
        \draw[xshift=-.2ex, bend right=20] (2*\x-.5,-.5) edge (2*\x+.5,.5);
        \draw[xshift=.2ex, bend right=20] (2*\x-.5,-.5) edge (2*\x+.5,.5);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}


\newlength{\ditto@width}
\NewDocumentCommand\dittotikzB{ s O{1em} m }{%
    % #1 = starred means horizontal line along entire width, unstarred means no line (only ditto marks)
    % #2 = minimum width
    % #3 = string to use for calculating width
    \settowidth{\ditto@width}{#3}%
    %\show\ditto@width%
    \edef\w{\ifdim#2<\ditto@width\the\ditto@width\else#2\fi}
    %\show\w%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1ex,y=1ex,baseline=-.5ex,cap=round]
        \tikzmath{
            \xfactor = \w / 4 * 1pt/1ex;
            \yfactor = .175;
        };
        %\show\xfactor;
        %\show\yfactor;
        \IfBooleanT{#1}{% starred
            \draw (0,0) sin (1\xfactor, \yfactor) cos (2\xfactor, 0) sin (3\xfactor, -\yfactor) cos (4\xfactor, 0);
        };
        \draw[xshift=-.2ex, bend right=20] (2\xfactor - .5, -.5) edge (2\xfactor + .5, .5);
        \draw[xshift=.2ex, bend right=20] (2\xfactor - .5, -.5) edge (2\xfactor + .5, .5);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}


\usepackage{xhfill}
\newcommand\ditto@symbol{%
    ||%
}
\NewDocumentCommand\dittoLatex{ s O{1em} m }{%
    % #1 = starred means horizontal line along entire width, unstarred means no line (only ditto marks)
    % #2 = minimum width
    % #3 = string to use for calculating width
    \settowidth{\ditto@width}{#3}%
    \makebox[{\ifdim#2<\ditto@width\ditto@width\else#2\fi}]{%
        \IfBooleanTF{#1}{% starred
            \xrfill[.5ex]{.4pt}%
            \ditto@symbol%
            \xrfill[.5ex]{.4pt}%
        }{%
            \ditto@symbol%
        }%
    }%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\let\ditto=\dittotikzA
\noindent
blah blah \ditto{} blah blah\\
blah blah \ditto[10em]{} blah blah\\

\let\ditto=\dittotikzB
\noindent
blah blah Test blah blah\\
blah blah \ditto{Test} blah blah\\
blah blah \ditto*{Test} blah blah\\
blah blah Testing testing blah blah\\
blah blah \ditto{Testing testing} blah blah\\
blah blah \ditto*{Testing testing} blah blah\\
blah blah \ditto{} blah blah\\
blah blah \ditto*{} blah blah\\
blah blah \ditto[10em]{Test} blah blah\\
blah blah \ditto*[10em]{Test} blah blah\\
blah blah \ditto[10em]{Testing testing} blah blah\\
blah blah \ditto*[10em]{Testing testing} blah blah\\
blah blah \ditto[10em]{} blah blah\\
blah blah \ditto*[10em]{} blah blah\\

\let\ditto=\dittoLatex
\noindent
blah blah Test blah blah\\
blah blah \ditto{Test} blah blah\\
blah blah \ditto*{Test} blah blah\\
blah blah Testing testing blah blah\\
blah blah \ditto{Testing testing} blah blah\\
blah blah \ditto*{Testing testing} blah blah\\
blah blah \ditto{} blah blah\\
blah blah \ditto*{} blah blah\\
blah blah \ditto[10em]{Test} blah blah\\
blah blah \ditto*[10em]{Test} blah blah\\
blah blah \ditto[10em]{Testing testing} blah blah\\
blah blah \ditto*[10em]{Testing testing} blah blah\\
blah blah \ditto[10em]{} blah blah\\
blah blah \ditto*[10em]{} blah blah\\

\end{document}
```

[image: example]

Some related questions:

- [Is there a ditto symbol?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53823/is-there-a-ditto-symbol) (has tikz)
- [How do I make ditto marks?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/442650/how-do-i-make-ditto-marks)
- [Quote (ditto marks) to avoid repeating a text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/513244/quote-ditto-marks-to-avoid-repeating-a-text)
- ["Same as above" representation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63236/same-as-above-representation/63242#63242)

Comment: Tipp: Use `\pgfmathsetmacro\y{#1*.01}` to evaluate the expression eagerly and avoid parsing oddities.

Comment: related "How do I make ditto marks?" : https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/442650/138900

Comment: @HenriMenke: that part of `\dittotikzA` works fine, it's just to adjust the amplitude of the sinus curve so it becomes more pronounced with length. I'm looking to make the width-calculation of `\dittotikzB` work.

Comment: @meide I know, that is why I wrote “Tipp” and not “Answer”.

Comment: inside tikz the font is \nullfont and so em and ex units are 0. You should at least use `\edef\w{\ifdim#2<\ditto@width\the\ditto@width\else\the\dimexpr#2\relax\fi}` to get pt inside \w.

Comment: Thanks @UlrikeFischer, however it still shows identical to the image above.

Comment: Use `4*\xfactor` instead of `4\xfactor` etc, or store your length in real length registers instead of using macros.

Comment: Aha, that works! If you post this as an answer, I will accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the multiplication signs. 4\xfactor is not 4*\xfactor.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{xparse}

\makeatletter

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\newcommand\w{}
\newlength{\ditto@width}
\NewDocumentCommand\dittotikzB{ s O{1em} m }{%
    % #1 = starred means horizontal line along entire width, unstarred means no line (only ditto marks)
    % #2 = minimum width
    % #3 = string to use for calculating width
    \settowidth{\ditto@width}{#3}%
    %\show\ditto@width%
    \edef\w{\ifdim#2<\ditto@width\the\ditto@width\else\dimexpr#2\relax\fi}
    %\show\w%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1ex,y=1ex,baseline=-.5ex,cap=round]
        \tikzmath{
            \xfactor = \w / 4 * 1pt/1ex;
            \yfactor = .175;
        };
        %\show\xfactor;
        %\show\yfactor;
        \IfBooleanT{#1}{% starred
            \draw (0,0) sin (1*\xfactor, \yfactor) cos (2*\xfactor, 0) sin (3*\xfactor, -\yfactor) cos (4*\xfactor, 0);
        };
        \draw[xshift=-.2ex, bend right=20] (2*\xfactor - .5, -.5) edge (2*\xfactor + .5, .5);
        \draw[xshift=.2ex, bend right=20] (2*\xfactor - .5, -.5) edge (2*\xfactor + .5, .5);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}



\makeatother

\begin{document}

\let\ditto=\dittotikzB
\noindent
blah blah Test blah blah\\
blah blah \ditto{Test} blah blah\\
blah blah \ditto*{Test} blah blah\\
blah blah Testing testing blah blah\\
blah blah \ditto{Testing testing} blah blah\\
blah blah \ditto*{Testing testing} blah blah\\
blah blah \ditto{} blah blah\\
blah blah \ditto*{} blah blah\\
blah blah \ditto[10em]{Test} blah blah\\
blah blah \ditto*[10em]{Test} blah blah\\
blah blah \ditto[10em]{Testing testing} blah blah\\
blah blah \ditto*[10em]{Testing testing} blah blah\\
blah blah \ditto[10em]{} blah blah\\
blah blah \ditto*[10em]{} blah blah\\



\end{document}
```